# How to create a custom UI and update the app without redirecting to playstore

Tags: flutter, google-play, in-app-update

I'm looking to create a custom UI for in-app updates. Once the user taps on a button the download should start automatically in the background. I tried [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_update), which does have background download functionality but custom UI cannot be created it seems.

Do you guys know some way to do this? For reference, I'm attaching a screen of CoinSwitch Kuber app who does that already and downloads the update in the background and once done, restart the app.

[image]